# remove sales offer label from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a task to remove specific sentence from a description field.
I suppose to use preg_replace, but can't find out how to do this at all.

input:
Here we have some text and then offer 25% and then some more text

Output should be:
Here we have some text and then and then some more text

So I need to remove **offer xx%** and any occurences of double space.

Anyone have a good expression for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm Maybe I just found the answer to some of it myself ... \boffer\b [0-9]+% ... Testing ...

Answer (score 0):

Try `offer \d+%`. It will match the literal string `offer` followed by `1` or `more` decimals followed by a `%` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
   $my_str = "Here we have some text and then offer 25% and then some more text";
   $changed_str = preg_replace("/[0-8]|[%]|(offer)/", " ", $my_str);

   print $changed_str ;
?>
```

output : Here we have some text and then and then some more text